# Exclude from brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I know that

```
echo {1..10}
```

do

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

but i do not want 6 and 7. Is it possible to exclude it?

Comment: Why not split the expansion `echo {1..5} {8..10}`

Comment: @Inian What if `echo {1..50}` and i do not want 22, 23, 25, 30, 33 like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with

```
echo {1..5} {8..10}
```

but One more solution I found:

```
echo {{1..5},{8..10}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the following:

```
echo {1..5} {8..10}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, `echo {1..5} {8..10}` may suffice.